# UIButtons overlapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I want to make an app that has a view that moves randomly or moves at the location where you touch the screen. I have the following problem: i made a button that begins a random animations and i want to make another button that stops the animation. The problem is that the two buttons are overlapping and only the first one is shown at the location of the second one, I press it and the second one is shown at the location where is supposed to be. I don't know what i am doing wrong, probably i have some problem with the subviews. Here is the code where i draw the buttons.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code

UIButton *randomMovementButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[randomMovementButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[randomMovementButton setTitle:@"Move Random" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
randomMovementButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self addSubview:randomMovementButton];

UIButton *stopButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[stopButton addTarget:self
            action:@selector(stopAnimation:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[randomMovementButton setTitle:@"Stop Moving Random" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
randomMovementButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 200.0, 40.0);
[self addSubview:stopButton];
}
```

Figured out my mistake, i was confused with the buttons' names and misused them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not overlapping. The second button does not have a frame. You wrote this:

```
UIButton *stopButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[stopButton addTarget:self
        action:@selector(stopAnimation:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[randomMovementButton setTitle:@"Stop Moving Random" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
randomMovementButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 200.0, 40.0);
[self addSubview:stopButton];
```

On the third and fourth line you wrote `randomMovementButton` instead of `stopButton`. This means both the Title and frame are set to the randomMovementButton and not the stopButton. Also, the frame on this second part and the first one are the same (Both are `CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 200.0, 40.0)`) which will make them overlap when you fix it. Change one of them.

Comment: Yes i know, it was a stupid mistake. Thank you. And btw, do you know how do i stop all animations at a current time?
@rickyman20

Comment: I generaly do not use uiview animations, but if you know a method that stops the animation of one uiview, you can loop through all the views like so:

for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        [subview stopAnimation];
    }

Comment: Also, I made up the stopAnimation method. I don't know if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use different frames for the two buttons and they will not overlap...

Comment: Could you please tell me how do i do this in code? Excuse me, but i don't have experience at all, i'm learning objective-c right now. Thank you very much.
@Mundi

Comment: Look at the code you posted. Just change the coordinates in one of your two `CGRectMake` functions. ;-)